# Rename a vbscript process

Tags: scripting, vbscript, wsh, scripting-language

When we run a `*.vbs` file, in processes, we used to get `"wscript.exe"`. We can change this `"wscript.exe"` to our custom name by creating a shortcut and executing the shortcut.

Is it possible to display the current `*.vbs` file name in process, without using shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your script is running in an interpreter, and it's the interpreter executable name that is being displayed in the process list.

While it's not impossible to change the process name, you'd need admin privileges to be able to do this, and you'd need to rewrite the interpreter (`wscript.exe`) to actually do it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3734473/1630171) to a similar question.