# How can I replace an entry in std::env:args()?

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, std

I would like to provide individual names to the threads in my Rust program. These names should appear in `top`/`htop` so I can differentiate the thread's job. In Ruby I would modify the `argv[0]` entry, or maybe `Process.setproctitle("foo")`. My inspiration is from Ruby's [Unicorn web server](https://varaneckas.com/blog/unicorn-procline/).

The `env::args` function returns an `Args` value. The `Args` value wraps the platform-specific `std::sys::args::args()` function which is not reexported for general use. [`ArgsOs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.ArgsOs.html) doesn't have a usable mutator (so yes, the stdlib makes it clear it is immutable).

How do I mutate the arguments some other way? I am happy with a Linux-only solution since that is where the real work will happen. Solutions outside the stdlib are also fine.

What path should I take in order to modify the first argument in the environment of my process?

Comment: *how my Rust program appears* ... *what all my threads are doing* — which is it? Do you care about the program as a whole or specific threads?

Comment: *In Ruby I would modify the `argv[0]` entry* — did you mean `ARGV`? I wasn't aware that this would change anything outside of the process. Searching for this functionality seems to be difficult, do you have any links so I can learn more about that functionality of Ruby?

Comment: (just realized that my link was wrong), A thread is NOT a process, why not use name when building the thread ? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html#method.name

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How can I replace an entry in `std::env:args()`

You cannot. Immutable means immutable.

> I would like to change how my Rust program appears in `top`/`htop`

There is nothing like this in the standard library. As far as I know, there's no cross-platform solution, so it would be a hard fight to put in there.

#### Linux

Seems to have a simple enough solution: [Change process name without changing argv[0] in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16165667/155423)

If you only care about Linux, you can use the [prctl](https://crates.io/crates/prctl) crate:

```
prctl::set_name("new_process")
```

#### macOS

Has various concepts of "process name" and the solution is complex and uses undocumented / hidden APIs: [Setting process name on Mac OS X at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4217947/155423)

Everything in that answer could be written in Rust using the appropriate bindings to the macOS APIs.

#### Windows

Does not seem to have such a concept: [Changing a process name in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3722852/155423)

#### Cross-Platform

Someone could write a crate that abstracts across these different mechanisms, but I'm not aware of one.

---

> so I can easily spot what all my threads are doing

As mentioned in the comments, when you create a thread, you can [give it a name](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html#method.name). Some work was recently put into [renaming threads at run time](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/44258), but that work stalled out.

Comment: kudos for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the [proctitle crate](https://crates.io/crates/proctitle) for setting process titles in a cross-platform manner.  On Linux it does happen to name the current *thread*, but this is a quirk of the APIs it provides rather than a deliberate choice.